# Delay: Toggle style (background image) Angular ng-class

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the following element in order to simply change the background-image between clicks on play and pause buttons.

```
<i ng-class="butcheck ? 'icon icon-share-link3-active' : 'icon icon-share-link3'" class="icon icon-share-link3" style=""></i>
```

However, the first click on Play triggers the style change, and it takes a bit time to show the pause background which feels like there is a gap between the transition.

Is there any way to preload the Pause background image for this specific case?
I see that it takes 174ms (size : 292 B).

In sum, really do not want the user to experience that gap. 
Any best practice in mind?
My workaround solution is as the following, but does not feel right.

```
 <div id="preload" class="icon-share-link3-active" style="display:none">
 </div>
```

It helps the style to be loaded in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example, images are preloaded and just some play of `z-index`

```css
/* Styles go here */
#d-1{
  background-image:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/rackcdn.kikvid.com/videos/09ba8757a890bb15e26494b5c40fd207/thumbnails/thumb_2_1280x720.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  min-height:300px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#d-2{
  background-image:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/rackcdn.kikvid.com/videos/68b50e453cedd89674f3337ef7f3eda3/thumbnails/thumb_0_1280x720.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  min-height:300px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
body *{
  color:#fff;
}
.z-1{
  z-index:-2; 
}
.z-2{
  z-index:-1; 
}
button{
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
      <div id="d-2" ng-class="d2?'z-2':'z-1'"></div>
      <div id="d-1" ng-class="d1?'z-2':'z-1'"></div>
      <h3>my block</h3>
      <p>my paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="toggle()">toggle</button>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.d1 = true;
          $scope.d2 = false;
          $scope.toggle = function(){
            $scope.d1 = !$scope.d1;
            $scope.d2 = !$scope.d2;
          }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```